# Is there a way to perform binary math on binary strings in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm working with some numbers that would be far too large for PHP to handle (IPv6 addresses in binary), so to work around this I've formulated a function to convert the addresses to/from binary strings (literally just a string of 1s and 0s). However, when it comes to subnet calculations the easiest way I know how to do this is to use binary math. I have no idea how I'd use binary math in this instance since I'm technically dealing with strings, not binary numbers. Is there any way I can do binary math with a string representation of a binary number?

Comment: What kind of math are you looking for? Because for masking & ranges `substr`, `strcmp` & `str_repeat` would almost suffice.

Comment: Well, definitely AND and OR, probably XOR as well. There could be more, but I know those three for sure will be needed.

Comment: Well, in that case [the GMP functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php) could help.

Comment: At a quick glance that looks exactly like what I'm looking for. I'll test it out in the next few hours and get back to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When working with large binary numbers you could use the [GMP extension](https://www.php.net/gmp). It accepts strings of arbitrary length as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was actually simple once I thought about it. I just wrote my own function to split the array into 32-character segments (to allow for 32-bit system compatibility, since 2^32 is the highest an integer can be on a 32-bit PHP implementation), perform the operation on each segment, and piece it back together afterward. However, the function enforces a binary string length of 128 (padding shorter ones if they're passed in) which is all I need. It could be easily reworked to allow any length of binary string. Here is the function:

```
function ipm_binmath($a, $b, $operand){
    $binregex = "/\b[01]*\b/";
    if (strlen($a) > 128 || strlen($b) > 128){
        throw new Exception("ipm_binmath accepts binary strings no greater than 128 characters.");
    }

    preg_match($binregex, $a, $amatches);
    preg_match($binregex, $b, $bmatches);

    if ($amatches[0] != $a){
        throw new Exception("Invalid data passed to ipm_binmath - \$a is not a binary string.");
    }
    if ($bmatches[0] != $b){
        throw new Exception("Invalid data passed to ipm_binmath - \$b is not a binary string.");
    }

    $aarr = str_split(str_pad($a, 128, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT), 32);
    $barr = str_split(str_pad($b, 128, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT), 32);
    $ret = "";

    for ($i=0; $i<4; $i++){
        switch (strtoupper(trim($operand))){
            case "AND":
                $ret .= str_pad(decbin((bindec($aarr[$i]) & bindec($barr[$i]))), 32, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
                break;
            case "OR":
                $ret .= str_pad(decbin((bindec($aarr[$i]) | bindec($barr[$i]))), 32, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
                break;
            case "XOR":
                $ret .= str_pad(decbin((bindec($aarr[$i]) ^ bindec($barr[$i]))), 32, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Unsupported or invalid operand passed to ipm_binmath: '" . $operand . "'");
                break;
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}
```